# ubuntu upgrading 18.04 to 20.04 - failing to boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partition, grub2, upgrade

Last night I was trying to upgrade from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 using the do-release-upgrade command. During the upgrade, the system logged me out and told me to reboot. After the reboot, I was unable to launch my windows (Bitlocker recovery) or ubuntu partitions (initramfs terminal). After the GNU GRUB v2.02 menu, selecting recovery options didn't make a difference (still logged into initramfs).

I tried to check the partition with fsck but didn't see any partitions resembling my drive.
[initramfs-prompts-busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860964/boot-drops-to-a-initramfs-prompts-busybox?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I was able to boot from a usb running xubuntu (only 1 out of 4 usbs worked for some reason) and got gparted to list my partitions:
[partitions list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLMZR.png)

After rebooting once again, I don't see the initramfs menu. Instead, I either got a black screen after selecting regular boot options or Recover Menu after selecting the recovery mode.

I tried boot-repair with a live usb
[grub-into-busybox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194328/grub-into-busybox) -
[boot-repair](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/11/install-boot-repair-ppa-fix-boot-problems/) -
[boot-repair summary](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/nrzXddBfRv/)

Issues persist as before (now the ubuntu text is smaller for some reason). After trying to boot ubuntu I see the manufacturer logo indefinitely (ASUS in search of incredible).

Booting in with nomodeset didn't seem to do anything (assuming I did it correctly).
[black-screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076)

from recovery mode -> root console

```
root@user$ fsck /dev/nvme0n1p6
root@user$ /dev/nvme0n1p6 is mounted e2fsck: Cannot continue aborting.
```

```
root@user$ fsck -nf /dev/nvme0n1p6

fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Warning! /dev/nvme0n1p6 is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 1448636 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter. Optimize? no
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free blocks count wrong (25787609, counted=12663609)
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong (12663604, counted 12663609)
Fix? no

/dev/nvme0n1p6: 1254604/13918208 files (0.4% non-contiguous), 29857319/55644928 blocks
```

running fsck from live usb running xubuntu

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p6
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/nvme0n1p6: clean, 1254602/13918208 files, 29857328/55644928 blocks
```

from grub terminal

```
grub> fsck
error: can't find command
```

```
grub> ls

(proc) (hd0) (hd0,gpt6) (hd0,gpt5) (hd0,gpt4) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1)
```

I've spent close to 12 hours on this now without much progress. Any advice on what to try next would be greatly appreciated. Should I try upgrading the BIOS? If i can't save my ubuntu partition, can I at least recover the windows one (haven't backed it up :|)

**Edit  1**

- Windows partition now works - found my BitLocker key in my Microsoft account.
- I'm running Intel integrated graphics
- ASUS ZenBook 14 UX433FA-DH74
- I don't see boot repair in BIOS
- I didn't find `/boot/grub.cfg`, instead I found `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` which I edited to remove all instances of `quiet splash`. Results are the same I think (flashing underscore "_" in the top left corner of screen).

```
grub> ls (hd0,gtp6)/boot 

efi/
grub/
config-5.4.0.47-generic
vmlinuz-5.4.0-47-generic
memtest86+.bin
memtest86+.elf
memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-5.4.0-48-generic
vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic
vmlinuz.old
initrd.img.old
System.map-5.4.0-48-generic
initrd.img-5.4.0-48
vmlinuz
System.map-5.4.0-47
initrd.img
initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic
```

Comment: try removing `quiet splash` from your `/boot/grub.cfg` then reboot to see which step fails and you can post those error here. The line should start with something like `menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux`. Also which graphics card do you have ? Don't worry your windows partition should be mostly fine. Also did you try boot-repair in `BIOS` mode or `UEFI` mode ?

Comment: you can also remove `quiet splash` interactively on grub console

Comment: Also before trying to fix anything. I recommend you to backup your ntfs partition if its really important to you `/dev/nvme0n1p3` .Your `/dev/nvme0n1p3` seems to be of size `241.5G ` boot into your usb and in terminal `cd` into where you have enough space of `241.5G  or greater (like external hd)` and run `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` and  following command `ntfsclone -s -o windows.img /dev/nvme0n1p3`.

Comment: @tinker I tried removing `quiet splash` by pressing `e` in the grub menu and editing the text. Following this I pressed ctrl-x. Results are the same (black screen).

Comment: @tinker I just managed to log into windows once again (found the bitlocker key in my microsoft account). It was encrypted so I couldn't mount it as ntfs before anyway. Now it's fine.

Comment: @tinker I'm on intel integrated graphics

Comment: hmm seems like even kernel is not loaded by bootloader. what's your output for `ls (hd0,gpt6)/boot` on grub console ?

Comment: @tinker `grub> ls (hd0,gtp6)/boot` `efi/ grub/ config-5.4.0.47-generic vmlinuz-5.4.0-47-generic memtest86+.bin memtest86+.elf memtest86+_multiboot.bin config-5.4.0-48-generic vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic vmlinuz.old initrd.img.old System.map-5.4.0-48-generic initrd.img-5.4.0-48 vmlinuz System.map-5.4.0-47 initrd.img initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic`

Comment: Ok so either its a corrupted kernel or maybe secure boot acting up. Have you tried booting other available kernel `5.4.0-48` and `5.4.0-47`?

Comment: @tinker yes i believe I tried both. None of the options in the GRUB menu work.